# Broadcast receiver crashing the app in some device

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am having an Android app where I am setting up some task using Broadcast Receiver and Alarm Manager. It's a very simple app like reminder where user create a reminder and system will awake the user with toast and a beep.

In my activity I set up the task as follows:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
MyAlarm alarm = new MyAlarm(MainActivity.this, bundle, sec);
```

My Alarm class is as follows:

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
private final String REMINDER_BUNDLE = "MyReminderBundle"; 
public MyAlarm(){ }

public MyAlarm(Context context, Bundle extras, int timeoutInSeconds){
     AlarmManager alarmMgr = 
         (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarm.class);
             intent.putExtra(REMINDER_BUNDLE, extras);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent =
         PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 
         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
     time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
     time.add(Calendar.SECOND, timeoutInSeconds);
     alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(),
                  pendingIntent);
 }

 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 Toast.makeText(context, "Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 try{
    playSound(context);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My playsound code is as follows:

```
public void playSound(Context context) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException,
  IOException {
Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, soundUri);
final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
  mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
  mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
  mMediaPlayer.prepare();
  mMediaPlayer.start();
 }
}
```

My problem is that it works good on Emulator and other device however it does not work with Samsung and Micromax devices.

`getList()` method:

```
public String getList(Context context,Date c)
 {
     String check = "Default";
     SQLiteDatabase sampleDB= context.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 Cursor cc = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME, null);  
 Log.d("Sent date is :-",c.toString());
 if(cc != null)
     if(cc.moveToFirst())
     do
     {
         Log.d("in do", "Success");
         Date v = new Date(cc.getString(2).trim());  
         if(v.getTime() - c.getTime() >= 0 && v.getTime() - c.getTime() <=1000){   
             Log.d("inside first if", "Success");
            Log.d("Number is",cc.getString(1));
            if(cc.getString(3).equals("ON")){
                 Log.d("inside second if", "Success");
                  try{
                         playSound(context);
                         }
                         catch(Exception e)
                         {

                         }
            Toast.makeText(context, "A call is scheduled for" + cc.getString(1)+".and it is about to be triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            check = cc.getString(1);
            break;
            }

         }

         }while(cc.moveToNext());

     sampleDB.close();
     return check;

 }
```

Below is my error logcat:

```
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.callsmsscheduler.MyAlarm: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error: Fri Dec 06 10:16:00 IST 2013
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2377)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:149)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error: Fri Dec 06 10:16:00 IST 2013
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at java.util.Date.parseError(Date.java:360)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:510)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:149)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at com.example.callsmsscheduler.MyAlarm.getList(MyAlarm.java:65)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at com.example.callsmsscheduler.MyAlarm.onReceive(MyAlarm.java:134)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2370)
12-06 10:17:59.424: E/AndroidRuntime(27514):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Can you post the crash call-stack?

Comment: Post your logcat error.

Comment: how can take out the logcat while testing on the device. Is there a way? I am new to android platform. Please help me out.

Comment: Eclipse has a save icon in the logcat window. You can save the output to a txt file.

Comment: Thanx for this suggestion however this gonna work if I m testing with an emulator how could it get a log if I am testing the app through a apk transfer and the clients sits nearly 200 km from me.

Comment: Error is about your date and time parse.... please post that getlist method...

Comment: where is your getList method?

Comment: I have posted the getList() methos where I am taking out a number which was scheduled before to be called. Here its check the current time with the time entered in database (current day, hour, minute, second) using getMillis of Date and return back the number.

Comment: Date v = new Date(cc.getString(2).trim()); Is this line causing the parsing error?

Comment: check my ans to replace this line let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Date v = new Date(cc.getString(2).trim());
```

Try something like this:

```
 SimpleDateFormat parserSDF=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        String dateInString = "7-Jun-2013";

        try {

            Date v= formatter.parse(dateInString);


        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Make sure your string is in valid format mentioned in SimpleDateFormat.

Checkout the changed SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

Comment: see I tried that I am geting Parse exception. I can not do the above method you know the date is saved in the data base with this format:
Fri Dec 06 15:43:00 IST 2013, what should be the formatter style for this?

Comment: I tried the above thing however logcat says the below thing

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Dec 06 16:12:00 IST 2013" (at offset 0)
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:618)

Comment: let me try executing it

Comment: Try EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy it's working for this string Fri Dec 06 16:12:00 IST 2013

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your line

```
Date v = new Date(cc.getString(2).trim());
```

with

```
Date v = SimpleDateFormat.parse(cc.getString(2).trim()))
```